# Scrollbar not working on Joomla

Tags: joomla

I have to say that I'm a complete beginner, and have a problem with scrollbar in my website. I have read in many posts that it can be something related with JQuery, but don't know if that's my case

This is my modest website http://www.lidergestup.es

Any help is appreciated :D

Comment: Hi, Could you please elaborate your issue in detail

Comment: Which scrollbar doesn't work? Please be more specific, thank you

Comment: Sorry! It was something related with updates. I have been experiencing this issue since many weeks ago but I updated my modules and it was solved. Thanks for your concern